Installing Java on Windows 11 - difference between Compressed Archive, Installer, and MSI Installer
When trying to install Java on my Windows 11, I saw three products available:
What's the difference among them?

x64 Compressed Archive
x64 Installer
x64 MSI Installer

So far I have found a Youtube video guide that recommends installing the MSI installer (short for "MicroSoftInstaller") without further explanation.

My guess: (a) the archive isn't an installer, so you probably don't want it; (b) the executable will probably just extract & run the MSI, (c) you should use the MSI.

The compressed archive is a package with all required files to run Java. This might be the correct solution if you want to have multiple versions of Java at the same time and really know what you are doing and how to set it up.
Both installers on the other hand are executables provided by Oracle to set everything up as you need it. This includes not only the required files as provided in the archive but also certain environment variables and windows configurations. This will typically be your best choice if you're an end user and don't need to dive into the inner workings of Java.
My best guess is, that the Installer is a certain installer provided by Oracle itself. It will contain routines to install Java as Oracle recommends it.
The MSI Installer on the other hand follows a certain format as dictated by Microsoft. This ensures that you can e.g. completely uninstall the software at a later time.

My personal recommendation is to use the MSI Installer when possible as it is a standardized format by Microsoft which comes with certain guaranteed benefits.
